# Can compilers change the order of declarations?

Tags: c, standards

In a declaration such as `int i, v[5], j;`, how will the variables be allocated? Is the compiler allowed to change their order?

Comment: As always, why? If you want to depend on the (relative) (stack?) locations, use a [struct and `offsetof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) to group the variables. Otherwise, compile with debug information and get the exact stack layout from the debug information

Comment: @sehe Does everything have to have a reason? I just want to know. :)

Comment: Duh - Yes. If the answer is yes, the compiler has a reason. If the answer is no, the compiler/standard has a reason. It is this reason you are essentially querying for yourself. You can't spit on rational analysis if you want facts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the compiler can do whatever it wants, as long as the meaning of the program stays the same. These variables might be optimized out of existence, stored only in a register, reused for other purposes, reordered for alignment requirments.

(note that a compiler cannot reorder variables within a struct)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the compiler can (and will) change the order. Ordering is compiler-specific and not specified in the C standards. The C standards don't even specify that a stack should exist.

Comment: Ordering is preserved in structs although alignment and padding may be added.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is allowed to **allocate** them pretty much wherever it wants.

Comment: I think OP is asking about the sequence of allocation and not on which part of stack.

Comment: I suppose, in **C** this would include initialization (as long as initialization doesn't depend on external factors)

Comment: @Mahesh: for auto variables, the order of the allocation _defines_ which part of the stack?